# Cannot add where clause to eloquent model

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

How do I add this `where clause` into `laravel eloquent model`

```
$proxSql = "(3958 * 3.1415926 * sqrt((Latitude - '.$lat.') * (Latitude - '.$lat.') 
              + cos(Latitude / 57.29578) * cos('.$lat.' / 57.29578) * (Longitude-'.$long.') * (Longitude - '.$long.')) / 180)";
$listings->where($proxSql, '<=', 5);
```

returns syntax error it seems laravel is adding ticks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A where clause isn't the right clause to use here.

You will need to use `whereRaw();`

https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queries#raw-methods

```
$listings->whereRaw($proxSql.' <= ?', [5]);
```

Comment: This answer does not use proper binding. You should bind your variables inside the `$procSql` variable, otherwise you might be prone to SQL injection attacks!

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using column-names directly in the query, you need to use `whereRaw()`. Otherwise it will be looking for a column-name of that variable `$proxSql`. You should also bind the variables while you're at it.

```
$proxSql = "(3958 * 3.1415926 * sqrt((Latitude - ?) * (Latitude - ?) 
              + cos(Latitude / 57.29578) * cos(? / 57.29578) * (Longitude - ? ) * (Longitude - ?)) / 180) <= 5";

$listings->whereRaw($proxSql, [$lat, $lat, $lat, $long, $long]);
```